# Refresh old cached data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I have Outputcache attribute above one of my controller action in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400)] // One day
public JsonResult GetCompanyName(int companyId)
{
    var company = _session.Get<Company>(companyId);

    if (company == null)
        throw new Exception();

    return Json(company.Name);
}
```

The reason behind the cache is that the companies we support doesn't change so often, so we don't need to query the data base for each HttpRequest with the same parameter.

If we add a new company how can I force the "re-check"?
Can it be done to this action only or I have to delete all my app cache?

**Update:** My data base is `Oracle` and my ORM is `NHibernate`

Comment: are you using a certain ORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw.aspx) method. So let's suppose that you have called the method like this to fetch the companies:

```
/somecontroller/getcompanyname/123
```

In order to expire this url from the cache so that the next time it is called it gets fresh results:

```
public ActionResult Expire()
{
    Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/somecontroller/getcompanyname/123");
    return Content("The cache was expired for the company with id = 123");
}
```

But IMHO for this scenario it would be better to use the second level cache of NHibernate to cache the results instead of caching the entire action with the OutputCache attribute. All that this action does is to return the JSON serialized object that came from the database. What is expensive is not the action call but the database call. So cache only the results of this database call (either using your ORMs cache or the system cache providers) as this will provide you with more robust control over the expiration policies of this cache.

Comment: Thanks. can you please give an example how to use NHibenate's second level cache for this scenario.

Comment: If the output is cached on the client browser. it saves the HTTP request, doesn't it?

Comment: @gdoron, NHibernate's second level cache usage probably deserves a separate question as it is not related to asp.net-mvc. As far as caching on the client browser is concerned, yes, it saves the HTTP request. But in your case is this HTTP request the most expensive thing compared to fetching the data from the database? I guess you will have to do some load tests on the system and compare the results in order to know which is better for your exact scenario.